# Expected BEGIN ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 and colum2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

This is json array data / json object data from api getting error expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 3 and column 2 path$

This is json array data / json object data from api getting error expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 3 and column 2 path$

This is json array data / json object data from api getting error expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 3 and column 2 path$

This is json array data / json object data from api getting error expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 3 and column 2 path$

```html
    "offersdata": [
        {
            "offercode": "GRAB20",
            "title": "Get Upto",
            "description": "20% off on selected merchandise on purchase of INR 1000 or more"
        },
        {
            "offercode": "JAN20",
            "title": "Get Upto",
            "description": "20% Off on all purchases in January"
        },
        {
            "offercode": "BHHH",
            "title": "DES",
            "description": "FDSFS"
        }
    ],
    "message": "success"
}
```

Interface

```html
 @GET("user")
    Call<List<limitedoffers>>  getoffers();
```

POJO CLASS

```js
package com.example.medico.models;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class limitedoffers {

    @SerializedName("offersdata")
    @Expose
    private List<Offersdatum> offersdata = null;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public List<Offersdatum> getOffersdata() {
        return offersdata;
    }

    public void setOffersdata(List<Offersdatum> offersdata) {
        this.offersdata = offersdata;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

```js
package com.example.medico.models;


import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class Offersdatum {

    @SerializedName("offercode")
    @Expose
    private String offercode;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;

    public String getOffercode() {
        return offercode;
    }

    public void setOffercode(String offercode) {
        this.offercode = offercode;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a `{` at the beginning of your json, is this intended ?

Comment: i cannot change the api thats the biggest problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read completely about **Retrofit**, **Retrofit** will work when the array is serialized perfectly.

```html
 "offersdata": [
        {
            "offercode": "GRAB20",
            "title": "Get Upto",
            "description": "20% off on selected merchandise on purchase of INR 1000 or more"
        },
        {
            "offercode": "JAN20",
            "title": "Get Upto",
            "description": "20% Off on all purchases in January"
        },
        {
            "offercode": "BHHH",
            "title": "DES",
            "description": "FDSFS"
        }
    ],
    "message": "success"
}
```

In the above Jsonarray **offersdata** has the ArrayList

In Interface class has to change code this

```
@GET("user")
Call<List<limitedoffers>>  getoffers();
```

to this

```
@GET("user")
Call<limitedoffers>  getoffers();
```

Because it doesn't contains ArrayList

For getting array from the **Limitedoffers** after the response Just use

```
response.body().getOffersdata();
```

to get the **offersdata** Arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, that's my favorite issue...

to resolve this you'll have to implement your [serializer](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/serialization/custom-serialization-readobject-writeobject/)

for your case you have to convert the coming object to the Array by yourself

Comment: Can you explain it for my problem